# now() returns wrong value when date() and server time are correct

Tags: php

`now();` = 1319959284

`date("Y/m/d");`
= 2011/10/30

if I run `date` on my server, the time is spot on

**edit 3** I'm an idiot

**edit 2** I am thinking that the UNIX timestamp is not the same as the MYSQL timestamp

**Edit 1**: I have only thought that to be wrong because when I try to insert this into a TIMESTAMP field in MYSQL, no digits are entered.

If I insert a number such as 20050224124736, it seems to be valid.

Screenshot of [PHPMYADMIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd2ra.png)

[another screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAji4.png)

Comment: Are you talking about MySQL's `NOW()` ?

Comment: What is `now()`? That's not a PHP function provided with the default distribution. Also, `1319959284` is UNIX time and appears correct.

Comment: I am using PHP's `NOW()`

Comment: is the root and mysql on the same server?

Comment: can we see your code? I'm guessing since its a phpmyadmin screenshot your talking about sql now() in an insert query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, that `now()` value corresponds to October 30th 2011, 07:21:24 UTC. Given that that's just a few minutes ago, it looks fine to me. What makes you think it's incorrect?

If for some reason you believe it's an hour out, perhaps that has something to do with many countries setting their clocks back last night?

EDIT: It sounds like PHPMYADMIN wants a value of the form

```
yyyyMMddHHmmss
```

So for now you'd type in

```
20111030074623
```

That sounds like it's worth a try at least...

EDIT: Looking at [this thread](http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?threadid=10326540) it seems the behaviour of MySQL changed around version 4.1. Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: PHPMYADMIN does not allow those digits to be entered manually into a TIMESTAMP field.

Comment: @Justin: So it looks like PHPMYADMIN wants a different format - that doesn't mean `now()` is wrong...